# Execvp(argv[1], argv), returning no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, exec, execvp

I am writing a C program that takes arguments, `char *argv[]` to decide which `exec()` to run. I have got `execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL)` to work fine. For some reason `execvp(argv[1], argv)` cannot find the 'ls' command to run. All I really need is if I have more than one argument, not including the call `./filexec`, I can run an `exec()` that will take the `char* argv[]` WITHOUT INCLUDING THE FILE PATH. I was under the understanding that `execvp()` had the capabilities to do this.

I am running this on ssh linux server.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pid_t pid;

        /* fork a child process */
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {/* error occured */
                fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
                return 1;
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {/* child process */
                //pass the right thing to the right exec?

                if (argc == 1)
                {
                        printf("CHILD started. No arguments provided. Terminating child.\n");
                }

                if (argc == 2)
                {
                        printf("CHILD started. One argument provided.      Calling execlp().\n");
                        execlp(argv[1],argv[1],NULL);
                }

                if (argc  >= 3)
                {
                        printf("CHILD started. More than one argument provided. Calling execvp().\n");
                        argv[argc++] = NULL;
                        execvp(argv[1],argv);
                }



        }
        else {/* parent process */
                /* parent will wait for the child to complete */
                printf("PARENT started, now waiting for processID#%u\n", getpid());
                wait(NULL);
                printf("PARENT resumed. Child exit code of 0. Now terminating parent.\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I expect giving `./a.out ls -l` to call `execvp()`
giving:

```
total XXX
info ---------filename
info ---------filename
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `argv[0]` is the "name of the program", so when your program is called it will be something like `./a.out`. Then `argv[1]` is the first argument to your program, which is the name of the program you want to `exec`, and the rest of `argv` is the rest of the arguments to pass to that program.

So the `argv` array you want to pass to the program you're going to exec starts at `argv[1]`. Or, more accurately, the `argv` pointer you want to provide the program you're going to `exec` is `argv + 1`.

You evidently figured that out for the call to `execlp`, since you specified `argv[1]` twice, once as the program name to `exec` and once as the first (and only) element in the `argv` array to pass to that program. You just need to do the same for the call to `execvp`; instead of `execvp(argv[1], argv)`, you need `execvp(argv[1], argv + 1)`.

The error message you're getting is from the `ls` utility itself. You've invoked `ls` with `execvp`, passing it your entire `argv` array. In other words, you've told it that its name is `./a.out` (which is probably a bit confusing, since most utilities use the program name they're given to create error messages), and you've provided it `ls -l` as command line arguments. That's effectively the same as the command line:

```
ls ls -l
```

which, if you try it, will very likely tell you that the file `ls` does not exist. (Unless you happen to have a file named `ls` in the current directory.)

By the way:

```
argv[argc++] = NULL;
```

is completely unnecessary. `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be NULL already, and you have no need for the variable `argc` (and if you had one, you'd probably need it to be one less, not one more).

Comment: Can I ask why the argv + 1 works? Does that just move the index starting at argv[1]? Skipping the ./a.out?

Comment: @cameronPrestera: This would be a good moment to go back to your C programming text book and look up pointer arithmetic. Understanding pointer arithmetic is really, really important.

Comment: From my understanding, anytime you have an array of pointers, doing a ++ or + 1 it moves to the next pointer in the array. I understand that, I guess my question is "Was the execvp taking the ./a.out as the first argument?", which I can see what that would cause an error.

Comment: @cameron: if you provide `argv` as an argument to `execvp`, that's what it thinks the argument is. The first thing in `argv` is `argv[0]`, and that's precisely what `execvp` will pass on to the program it runs.